# What is the best way to configure an ALB to deal with a regional outage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

We have a basic ALB with four availability zones, all in us-east-1[abcd]. Last week, we were effected by this outage at Amazon:

> [03:42 PM PDT] Between 11:49 AM PDT and 3:37 PM PDT, we experienced
> increased error rates and latencies for multiple AWS Services in the
> US-EAST-1 Region. Our engineering teams were immediately engaged and
> began investigating. We quickly narrowed down the root cause to be an
> issue with a subsystem responsible for capacity management for AWS
> Lambda, which caused errors directly for customers (including through
> API Gateway) and indirectly through the use of other AWS services.
> Additionally, customers may have experienced authentication or sign-in
> errors when using the AWS Management Console, or authenticating
> through Cognito or IAM STS.

My question is: how fault-tolerant is ALB if all of your availability zones are in the same region? For anyone who has knowledge of this outage, would selecting a zone in Boston or Atlanta given us better failover than chosing all the zones from us-east-1*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ALB can't cope with a regional outage. An ALB has nodes in each AZ of a single region.

To cope with a regional outage you need to use multiple regions. You direct traffic between regions using Route53, using whichever type of split you prefer, based on Route53 health checks. You could:

- Direct 100% of your traffic to your primary region while it's working
- Split the traffic 50 / 50 between two regions. This might reduce user latency but also could make database consistency more challenging.
- Split traffic 95 / 5 just to prove the second region is always working
- You could alternate between regions for each deployment, blue / green style

The other region can be standby, pilot light, or hot.

- Standby: very few, perhaps a load balancer with auto-scaling scaled down to zero (I've not tried this but I think it's possible)
- Pilot light: a very small amount of resources
- Hot: scaled to take full production load

Answer (score 2):

An ALB can only LB between zones within a region. If your whole region is impacted, you need to have HA or failover to another region.

There's no single region you can pick that will never have an outage.